# How do I use an mfc application's dialog box in a separate mfc console application?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, modal-dialog

I have two MFC applications. One of them is just a dialog box with some functions to support it and the other is a console application. How do I make the console application able to open the dialog box located in the other application?

I have tried building the dialog application as a dll and importing it. Also, adding the existing project to the console project and linking them that way. While I believe I got the linking down, I can never make the console instantiate the dialog. It's possible I am going about this part the wrong way too.

Is there an easy way to export the dialog I created and import it into another program? If i created a project called "input" and it made inputDlg.h/inputDlg.cpp, why can't I just move those into another project and call on things from them? Or is using a dialog outside it's initial project not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what I needed:

1. I opened up the resource file for both projects in Visual Studio and simply copy/pasted the dialog I wanted to transfer in resource view.
2. I then closed everything and opened up the console project. It contained the dialog box I transferred. I double clicked it in the resource view and it opened up.
3. It still didn't have a class associated with it yet so i double clicked the frame and the class wizard opened up. I named it the same as it was called in the first dialog project (WhateverDlg.h/WhateverDlg.cpp).
4. Then I was able to copy and paste my code over from the dialog project, to the console project. I only had to remove a couple lines that referenced the wrapper (Whatever.h) and it was done.

This made me able to include WhateverDlg.h in my console program and use DoModal(). Success!

Answer (score 0):

A dialog (or any other GUI windows) needs a message pump, but a console application does not normally have a message pump. If you want the console app to just wait until the dialog is closed, the easiest way to do this is to use Win32 APIs instead of MFC. Just create a dialog by calling DialogBox. This API provides its own message loop.

Otherwise you will have a take a multithreaded approach, with the console running in the main thread. Start a secondary thread with a message pump in it and create your CDialog-based dialog in that thread.

Comment: The first paragraph is a little bit confusing. From the first sentence, I was thinking "that's not correct, modal dialog boxes provide their own message pump". But then, you said that at the end. The problem is just that the MFC classes hack around the standard modality mechanism.